# Use multiple firebase accounts in single android app for google analytics

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-cloud-messaging

I have a use case in which 1 app will be used by multiple separate companies (franchises) that will have their own marketing and management teams. I need the user to select a franchise when the mobile app starts up, and then from that point on, push all analytics data to that franchise's firebase (google analytics) account. Similarly any push notifications that are sent from that franchise's servers need to go to the user.

Is this configuration possible? In the past I used to set up a google analytics account for each franchise and just download the UA-xxx number from the server on franchise selection, and then set up the google analytics object based on that..

What is the appropriate way to achieve this via firebase connected to google analytics ?

I found the offical API reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/ 
This link explains how to do it for iOS but doesn't mention how to do it in android. It does say however that the firebase init runs before user code.. perhaps that means it is not possible?

Here is the init provider they mention: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/provider/FirebaseInitProvider

Answer (score 23, accepted):

create for each new firebase app

```
    FirebaseApp firebaseApp = 
          FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context, FirebaseOptions,firebaseAppName);
```

you can **create firebase app** by passing options:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions.Builder

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setApiKey(String)
    .setApplicationId(String)
    .setDatabaseUrl(String)
    .build();
```

then **when You want to use Analytics you need to set default one** by call:

```
FirebaseApp firebaseApp = 
      FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context, FirebaseOptions,"[DEFAULT]");
```

keep in mind that only this **DEFAULT** firebase app will be used in analytics

but first off all you need to **remove init provider in manifest**

```
        <!--remove firebase provider to init manually -->
    <provider
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
        tools:node="remove"/>
```

and **init default firebase app manually**!

example how to send event via default firebase app(after initialized):

```
// get tracker instance
FirebaseAnalytics trakerInstance = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context);
// create bundle for params
Bundle params = new Bundle();
// put param for example action
params.putString(ACTION_KEY, eventAction);
// send event 
trackerInstance.logEvent(eventCategory, params);
```

> @ceph3us I tried your solution, and it didn't work for me. If I
>   initialise firebase at runtime as you suggested then I get an error:
>   Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. Are you sure it is
>   working? – rMozes

first of all

1. did you **removed default provider by putting in manifest tools:node="remove"**?
2. did u **initialized  ['DEFAULT'] firebase app**  as i described
3. did you **check if a ['DEFAULT'] firebase app is initialized before sending any event** ?

ad 1) the  `error: Missing google_app_id` suggests me that gardle plugin didn't removed provider as expected - and your app is starting a default provider which complains about missing app id

ad 3) don't do any calls relying on firebase app before firebase app is initialized

```
    protected boolean isDefaultFirebaseAppInitialized() {
        try {
            // try get
            return FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.DEFAULT_APP_NAME) != null;
            // catch illegal state exc
        } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
            // on such case not initialized
            return false;
        }
    }

// check on default app 
if(isDefaultFirebaseAppInitialized()) {
    // get tracker 
    FirebaseAnalytics trakerInstance = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context);
    // log event 
    trackerInstance.logEvent(eventCategory, params);
} else {
    // postpone
}
```

> @ceph3us 1. I removed the provider as you said, if I wouldn't remove
>   the provider and try to initialise the default app then I would get a
>   IllegalStateException about default firebase app already exists. 2. I
>   initialised default firebase app as you described. 3. Yes, I logged
>   the app name and app_id and there is a log: AppName: [DEFAULT], Google
>   app id: valid_app_id But when I want to post something to analytics,
>   then it says that: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled.
>   – rMozes

**99,99% you are trying to send event before app is initialized !** (see above example)

> @ceph3us I initialise FirebaseApp in the onCreate method of
>   Application subclass. I send event to firebase when a button is
>   clicked. Anyway I uploaded a test project to github, can you take a
>   look at it? It is possible I misunderstand something.
>   github.com/rMozes/TestFirebaseAnalytics – rMozes

try (as initialization is asynchronous - so until you test its initialized you cant send events):

https://github.com/rMozes/TestFirebaseAnalytics/compare/master...c3ph3us:patch-2

***if above fails you have two more chances :)***

**by define the string in xml**: as a placeholder

```
<string name="google_app_id">fuck_you_google</string>
```

1) **change the placeholder id via reflections** to other one before any call to init/or use from firebase:

[hint how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674925/change-value-of-r-string-programically/42936357#42936357)

2) **provide a own text for the placeholder id** via own Resources class implementation for Resources.getString(R.string.google_app_id) call:

an [example how to achieve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126549/android-dynamically-add-item-to-array-xml-resource/49344488#49344488)  (adding a new resources by id)

if you proper change R field  via reflections or substitute a call to Resources.getString(R.string.google_app_id) with own text **you will not get message wrong app id: "fuck_you_google"**

& good luck :)

Comment: please would you expand a little more ?

Comment: do you still need the .json file with this solution?

Comment: is there any change to how the analytics calls are made? or are they still done in the standard way?

Comment: no but only you can call analytics api only for default app so u need to switch them passing different options

Comment: One last comment, why is there an `=` sign before the initApp command line with the [DEFAULT]  ?

Comment: i added example how to call event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151276/discussion-between-user230910-and-ceph3us).

Comment: i have implemented this in my code, but when I try to post to google analytics i get an error: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. - Do you perhaps know what step i'm missing?

Comment: @ceph3us I tried your solution, and it didn't work for me. If I initialise firebase at runtime as you suggested then I get an error:  Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled.
Are you sure it is working?

Comment: @ceph3us
1. I removed the provider as you said, if I wouldn't remove the provider and try to initialise the default app then I would get a IllegalStateException about default firebase app already exists.
2. I initialised default firebase app as you described.
3. Yes, I logged the app name and app_id and there is a log:
AppName: [DEFAULT], Google app id: valid_app_id
But when I want to post something to analytics, then it says that:
Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled.

Comment: @rMozes try remove app from phone reboot  reinstall then try once again

Comment: did u wait until app initialized ? before sending event - as i gave u example ? "But when I want to post something to analytics, then it says that: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled.",  and post exact logs from app start

Comment: @ceph3us I initialise FirebaseApp in the onCreate method of Application subclass. I send event to firebase when a button is clicked. Anyway I uploaded a test project to github, can you take a look at it? It is possible I misunderstand something.
https://github.com/rMozes/TestFirebaseAnalytics

Comment: initialization is asynchronous - so until you test its initialized you cant send events i will look at code when ill get back from walk :)

Comment: @ceph3us I tried it, but the same result. What do you think, what could be the problem? I really don't have any idea

Comment: @ceph3us - we are so close, i'm willing to give 100 rep to finish this one off

Comment: @rMozes do as i described in last step :) - create resource entry with app id and change it via reflection to desired one after onCreate in App class before call to initialize firebase

Comment: Direction from Google is that it is not possible to set different appId at runtime for FirebaseAnalytics. And it seems no one has managed to get this solution working successfully. Why has it been upvoted?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to have multiple Firebase instance in your apps

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
   .setApplicationId("Your AppId") // Required for Analytics.
   .setApiKey("You ApiKey") // Required for Auth.
   .setDatabaseUrl("Your DB Url") // If you wanted to
   .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options, "CompanyA");
```

Which you can get Firebase instances by

```
FirebaseApp appCompanyA = FirebaseApp.getInstance("CompanyA");
```

You can see the full example use of Auth and Realtime Database using multiple Firebase instance [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html)

I'll leave this solution here which may duplicate with another answers for someone who might need this

Hope this help :)

Comment: great, so this bypassed the need for the .json file completely ?

Comment: @user230910 yes, and when you using firebase analytic to send any event you could use different com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker

Comment: show me how you call to send analytics event here :))

Comment: thanks for the hard work answering my question, appreciate it :)