# Using FirebaseAnalytics from inside a library

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I want to use [`FirebaseAnalytics`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics) inside a library project on android. I want the events logged to be reported to my Firebase console and not to the console of the app developer. I do not own or control the implementation of the app that will use the library.

Is this possible in any way?

My approach:

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45546833/use-multiple-firebase-accounts-in-single-android-app-for-google-analytics) and found out that it is possible to create a `FirebaseApp` using my credentials as follows:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setApplicationId("Your AppId") // Required for Analytics.
    .setApiKey("You ApiKey") // Required for Auth.
    .setDatabaseUrl("Your DB Url") // If you wanted to
    .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options, "CompanyA");
```

Is there a way to use this `FirebaseApp` to log events as in `FirebaseAnalytics`?

Comment: I was also researching for a method to do that, and I don't think it is possible right now.